Catholic Confirmation during Covid-19?
During the Covid-19 pandemic, the sacrament of Catholic confirmation was temporarily changed, in some locations. The changes involved no touch what so ever, instead implements were used. This violates Code of Canon Law, even Pope Paul 6 forbid the use of implements. How were those confirmations during Covid "really" valid? There are priests who have contended it was not valid. Canon Law specifies human touch to administer the oil. The Bible specifies human touch. Also a document was released this year by the Vatican which specified the sacraments must be done according to Canon Law. Someone please make this make sense.

sources would help make this question better

Catholic Confirmation during Covid-19?
The Sacrament of Confirmation must be administered according to the norms of the Catholic Church. Otherwise they are invalid!
According to the Catechism of the Catholic Church, the sacrament of confirmation must be administered through the anointing of sacred chrism through the hands of the local bishop (or priests wth the proper faculties).

The celebration of Confirmation
1297 The consecration of the sacred chrism is an important action that precedes the celebration of Confirmation, but is in a certain way a part of it. It is the bishop who, in the course of the Chrism Mass of Holy Thursday, consecrates the sacred chrism for his whole diocese. In some Eastern Churches this consecration is even reserved to the patriarch:
The liturgy of Antioch expresses the epiclesis for the consecration of the sacred chrism (myron) in this way: "[Father . . . send your Holy Spirit] on us and on this oil which is before us and consecrate it, so that it may be for all who are anointed and marked with it holy myron, priestly myron, royal myron, anointing with gladness, clothing with light, a cloak of salvation, a spiritual gift, the sanctification of souls and bodies, imperishable happiness, the indelible seal, a buckler of faith, and a fearsome helmet against all the works of the adversary."
1298 When Confirmation is celebrated separately from Baptism, as is the case in the Roman Rite, the Liturgy of Confirmation begins with the renewal of baptismal promises and the profession of faith by the confirmands. This clearly shows that Confirmation follows Baptism. When adults are baptized, they immediately receive Confirmation and participate in the Eucharist.
1299 In the Roman Rite the bishop extends his hands over the whole group of the confirmands. Since the time of the apostles this gesture has signified the gift of the Spirit. The bishop invokes the outpouring of the Spirit in these words:

All-powerful God, Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, by water and the Holy Spirit
you freed your sons and daughters from sin
and gave them new life. Send your Holy Spirit upon them to be their helper and guide. Give them the spirit of wisdom and understanding, the spirit of right judgment and courage, the spirit of knowledge and reverence. Fill them with the spirit of wonder and awe in your presence.


We ask this through Christ our Lord.

1300 The essential rite of the sacrament follows. In the Latin rite, "the sacrament of Confirmation is conferred through the anointing with chrism on the forehead, which is done by the laying on of the hand, and through the words: 'Accipe signaculum doni Spiritus Sancti' [Be sealed with the Gift of the Holy Spirit.]."114 In the Eastern Churches of Byzantine rite, after a prayer of epiclesis, the more significant parts of the body are anointed with myron: forehead, eyes, nose, ears, lips, chest, back, hands, and feet. Each anointing is accompanied by the formula SfragiV dwreaV PneumatoV �Agiou (Signaculum doni Spiritus Sancti): "the seal of the gift of the Holy Spirit."
1301 The sign of peace that concludes the rite of the sacrament signifies and demonstrates ecclesial communion with the bishop and with all the faithful.

I am aware of some dioceses that postponed the sacrament of confirmation until after the Covid-19 pandemic was over and other dioceses that allowed pastors to administer this sacrament in small groups in order the follow local health care Covid-19 social distancing rules.
Using implements to anoint confirmands is contrary to how the Church administers the sacrament and is invalid.
Even during Covid-19, priests were administering Holy Communion without implements of one kind or another!
If a particular dioceses had a dispensation from Rome to act in such a way, let them prove it with a copy of the dispensation. After all, such documents should be a available to the faithful also. I highly doubt Rome accorded such documents.

Thank you for your reply! I agree with you whole hearted! This was the resource from USCCB.  https://www.usccb.org/resources/newsletter-2020-07-and-08.pdf       You can scroll to page 24 there was a reply to a Dublium questioning the use of an implement. Which is against canon law and even forbidden by Paul IV.
Thank you again for your reply.

See also https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_ddf_doc_20240202_gestis-verbisque_en.html.      Which upholds that sacraments MUST be done according to canon law - which forbids implements - lol
